# Creating SQL procedure for updating inventory when a new order is added

Tags: mysql

Like the title says, I'm trying to make an SQL procedure for updating inventory when an order is added. I have one table for orders, and another table kalt "ordrelinje". (I don't know what you would call it en english, sorry). The "ordrelinje" table stores what item's been sold, along with the quantity of the item being sold.

I'll add a picture of the ER-diagram:

[image]

This is the code for the procedure which I have so far:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE oppdatereAntallVarerVedSalg(
IN inOrdreID INT, inBrukerID INT, inOrdreStatus VARCHAR(25), 
   inOrdreDato DATE, inVareID INT, inMengde INT)
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO ordre VALUES (inOrdreID , inBrukerID , inOrdreStatus , inOrdreDato);

    INSERT INTO ordrelinje VALUES (inOrdreID , inVareID , inMengde);

    UPDATE vare 
        SET antall =antall - inMengde
    WHERE vareID = inVareID;

    COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This procedure seems to almost work. Only problem is that when I test the procedure with for instance the sale of milk, double the amount of what I input is subtracted from the vare-table. When I input a sale of 100 milk, 200 is subtracted.

Comment: Is this MySQL? If so, don't tag as Microsoft SQL Server, an unrelated dialect.

Comment: Ok, sorry. It came up as a suggested tag, and I just read SQL. I'm new to this, so I didn't know there was a difference. Won't happen again.

Comment: Not a huge deal, just asking for clarification. These are two different dialects with often contradictory solutions.

Comment: What is the primary key for ordrelinje? It appears there is none - which would be a serious schema problem. Next, you should learn best practices. Always provide a column list in your insert statement - that will avoid (or highlight) problems in the future when the columns are changed or re-ordered.

Comment: Lastly - Do any of these tables have triggers? In particular, ordrelinje?

Comment: yes, I know. this database is completely messed up. It's a group project in uni, so it would be very hard for me to change the database right now, because I have to take into account 5 other peoples (who are all beginners) opinions.
And yes. We have solved this problem using triggers. But we need to ALSO do it with procedures, because it's part of the assignment.

Comment: Order_line_item or order_detail seem like reasonable translations

Comment: I suspect a trigger is updating the vare table also. That's why the amount being subtracted is double what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you mr. Wilson, that was correct!